# access 2003 import specs not working in access 2010

Tags: ms-access, import, vba, etl

I migrated an Access 2003 DB to Access 2010. No major changes were done to any of the VBA subroutines or functions.

A couple of our subroutines that utilize Import Specifications to perform ETL tasks do not work. After a bit of digging around, I noticed that the import specs that were created in v2003 were not appearing in the v2010 `Saved Imports` menu.

I thought they simply had not carried over to v2010 and I would need to re-create the specs. When I did this through the `Import Text Wizard`, and clicked `Advanced` --> `Specs...`, I noticed that the specs created in v2003 actually *are* listed there. However, this is of no help, because they don't work when referenced in VBA.

Does anyone know how to make v2010 "recognize" specs that were created in v2003?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

There is a column in the `MSysIMEXspecs` **system table** named `SpecType`. This system table contains references to all saved import specs.

The specs that had been created in v2003 that did not work in v2010 were all listed in this table, but they had values of `2` in this field. A new spec I had created in v2010 just for testing had a value of `1` in here.

I flipped the values of the v2003 specs to `1` and they could then be referred to from the VBA subs/functions.

**Edit:** From [this](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d870199/logiciels/microsoft-office/access/vba-access/msysimexspecs-spectype/) link I learned that in the `SpecType` table, `1` means `delimited` and `2` means `fixed`.